# How to enhance the code style with mongodb and twilio whatsapp bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, twilio

I have this Whatsapp bot made using Twilio and persistent with mongodb due to the nature of the logic I am following the code is become more of a cluttered and seems un-pythonic. It works fine as I expected but my problem is I can't figure out a way to make it little bit clean.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime


cluster = MongoClient("URL")
db = cluster["bakery"]
users = db["users"]
orders = db["orders"]

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["get", "post"])
def reply():
    text = request.form.get("Body")
    number = request.form.get("From")
    number = number.replace("whatsapp:", "")[:-2]
    res = MessagingResponse()
    user = users.find_one({"number": number})
    if bool(user) == False:
        msg = res.message("Hi, thanks for contacting *The Red Velvet*.\nYou can choose from one of the options below: "
                    "\n\n*Type*\n\n 1️⃣ To *contact* us \n 2️⃣ To *order* snacks \n 3️⃣ To know our *working hours* \n 4️⃣ "
                    "To get our *address*")
        msg.media("https://i.ibb.co/BPKnXVP/Red-Velvet-Cake-Waldorf-Astoria.jpg")
        users.insert_one({"number": number, "status": "main", "messages": []})
    elif user["status"] == "main":
        try:
            option = int(text)
        except:
            res.message("Please enter a valid response")
            return str(res)

        if option == 1:
            res.message(
                "You can contact us through phone or e-mail.\n\n*Phone*: 991234 56789 \n*E-mail* : contact@theredvelvet.io")
        elif option == 2:
            res.message("You have entered *ordering mode*.")
            users.update_one(
                {"number": number}, {"$set": {"status": "ordering"}})
            res.message(
                "You can select one of the following cakes to order: \n\n1️⃣ Red Velvet  \n2️⃣ Dark Forest \n3️⃣ Ice Cream Cake"
                "\n4️⃣ Plum Cake \n5️⃣ Sponge Cake \n6️⃣ Genoise Cake \n7️⃣ Angel Cake \n8️⃣ Carrot Cake \n9️⃣ Fruit Cake  \n0️⃣ Go Back")
        elif option == 3:
            res.message("We work from *9 a.m. to 5 p.m*.")

        elif option == 4:
            res.message(
                "We have multiple stores across the city. Our main center is at *4/54, New Delhi*")
        else:
            res.message("Please enter a valid response")
    elif user["status"] == "ordering":
        try:
            option = int(text)
        except:
            res.message("Please enter a valid response")
            return str(res)
        if option == 0:
            users.update_one(
                {"number": number}, {"$set": {"status": "main"}})
            res.message("You can choose from one of the options below: "
                        "\n\n*Type*\n\n 1️⃣ To *contact* us \n 2️⃣ To *order* snacks \n 3️⃣ To know our *working hours* \n 4️⃣ "
                        "To get our *address*")
        elif 1 <= option <= 9:
            cakes = ["Red Velvet Cake", "Dark Forest Cake", "Ice Cream Cake",
                     "Plum Cake", "Sponge Cake", "Genoise Cake", "Angel Cake", "Carrot Cake", "Fruit Cake"]
            selected = cakes[option - 1]
            users.update_one(
                {"number": number}, {"$set": {"status": "address"}})
            users.update_one(
                {"number": number}, {"$set": {"item": selected}})
            res.message("Excellent choice ")
            res.message("Please enter your address to confirm the order")
        else:
            res.message("Please enter a valid response")
    elif user["status"] == "address":
        selected = user["item"]
        res.message("Thanks for shopping with us ")
        res.message(f"Your order for *{selected}* has been received and will be delivered within an hour")
        orders.insert_one({"number": number, "item": selected, "address": text, "order_time": datetime.now()})
        users.update_one(
            {"number": number}, {"$set": {"status": "ordered"}})
    elif user["status"] == "ordered":
        res.message("Hi, thanks for contacting again.\nYou can choose from one of the options below: "
                    "\n\n*Type*\n\n 1️⃣ To *contact* us \n 2️⃣ To *order* snacks \n 3️⃣ To know our *working hours* \n 4️⃣ "
                    "To get our *address*")
        users.update_one(
            {"number": number}, {"$set": {"status": "main"}})
    users.update_one({"number": number}, {"$push": {"messages": {"text": text, "date": datetime.now()}}})
    return str(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Basically I am trying to adding user and updating user with the latest status e.g `status["user"] == "main"` I am recording the status in the database as well as using it as a flag to identify the user at which flow they are currently to give output the appropriate response. I'm fairly new to mongodb and I couldn't figure out a way to make it more organize and human readable. If anyone here could help me out with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use folders that contain files that perform specific actions:

> config (folder)
>
> > db.py (for MongoDB client connection and database creation)

> Twilio
>
> > reply.py (for the reply function)

> > Routes
> > routes.py (for the routes of the URL, if required in the case)

> app.py (that contains the flask `app` and call necessary files)

If you are comfortable with `FastAPI` then you can explore and use that with Twilio and MongoDB as it has various other benefits over Flask and cleaner code as well.